# Passing perameters into model formset

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to pass some variables into a model formset. I've looked at the official django documentation and they talk about doing this with a regular, non-model formset. I can't get this to work for a modelformset though.

views.py

```
EmployeeTeamFormset = modelformset_factory(EmployeeTeamMembership, form=EmployeeTeamForm(), extra=0, max_num=10, can_delete=True)

formset = EmployeeTeamFormset(request.POST or None, queryset=EmployeeTeamMembership.objects.filter(employee__user=user, team=team), kwargs={'user': user, 'team': team})
```

forms.py

```
class EmployeeTeamForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = EmployeeTeamMembership
        fields = ('employee', 'team_lead',)  

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):                
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        self.team = kwargs.pop('team', None)
```

I get the following error:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kwargs'
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of typos in my code. This works:

```
EmployeeTeamFormset = modelformset_factory(EmployeeTeamMembership, form=EmployeeTeamForm, extra=0, max_num=10, can_delete=True)



formset = EmployeeTeamFormset(request.POST or None, queryset=EmployeeTeamMembership.objects.filter(employee__user=user, team=team), form_kwargs={'user': user, 'team': team})
```